# Spring triple load controller on server start

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am using Tomcat 7 with Spring MVC 3.2.x RELEASE. The spring template code is generated by Intellij, I just added an syserr message output.

When I start the server the default controller is called three times, and only on start up, after that it works fine. Is there a configuration error on my part or is it a bug?

Here is the configuration files:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    private static int t = 0;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        System.err.println("Print num: " + (++t));
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

//Output

```
INFO: Root mapping to handler 'helloController'
Jun 22, 2013 1:41:21 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 413 ms
[2013-06-22 01:41:21,561] Artifact SpringTest:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
Print num: 1
Print num: 2
Print num: 3
Jun 22, 2013 1:41:22 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jun 22, 2013 1:41:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Milky\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\manager
```

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

```xml
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I test this code using Spring 3.1 and tomcat7, but got 'Print num: 1' one time.

Comment: I tried this out in eclipse and didn't get said behavior. I think it may be just an Intellij issue. I'll go file a bug with them

Comment: same problem.how did you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The сontroller method can be called three times when using `Intellij IDEA` (when the application starts) - because of the server configuration `"After launch"` setting.

You can try unselecting it: [screenshot from server configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvYL5.png)